# Dump data from beeline in HDFS directory

Tags: hadoop, hive, hdfs, beeline

i am writing a bash script to export dynamic sql query into a hql file in HDFS directory.I am going to run this bash through oozie.

1. sql_v= select 'create table table_name from user_tab_columns where ...;'
2. beeline -u "$sql_v" > local_path

sql_v variable will store dynamic create table command which i want to store in a hql file in hdfs directory. If i run above 2 steps it runs fine because i am storing data in local path but instead of passing local_path i want to store sql in hdfs directory.Is there a way i can pass hdfs path instead of local_path like below but this doesn't work. Can i use any other command instead of beeline to achieve this ?

beeline -u "$sql_v" | hdfs dfs -appendToFile -

Comment: Why not use an `INSERT INTO` query?

Comment: INSERT into can store query in hdfs file ? how

Comment: Hive isn't a database... It's just a collection of HDFS files that you're querying. So inserting into a table (or creating a table from a selection) will generate HDFS files (though, not "hql files", whatever those are)

Comment: i only want to store the query in hql file and not the result of query

Comment: something like this :sql_v= select 'create table table_name from user_tab_columns where ...;'

beeline -u "$sql_v"  | hdfs dfs -appendToFile -destination

Comment: Maybe I'm misunderstanding the purpose of the `appendToFile`, then. Looks like you're trying to run a query, then upload the results to HDFS, when you could do that entirely within your "dynamic query"... Which you can pass to Oozie with the `<file>` tag

Comment: Also, I think you're looking for `create table table_name as select`, not `select 'create table...'`. Then it's `beeline -e` to evaluate a query

Comment: you are right , i want to pass the dynamic query to Oozie.i have not shared the full query but this query will go in Oracle and copy same table structure in hive but with different datatypes. Issue is i am not able to store this dynamic query in HDFS path using beeline. as beeline could only connect to local path.

Comment: Beeline shouldn't need to pull the query from HDFS. If you're generating the query as a string in a local bash session, why do you need a query file at all?

Comment: i am not trying to pull the query but store this query in HDFS in hql file using beeline

Comment: Beeline isn't used to just store a string in HDFS. Why can't you write the query to a file `echo "$sql_v" > file.hql`, then `hdfs dfs -put file.hql /tmp`?

Comment: so the output of this query is another CREATE TABLE query which i want to store in HDFS so thats why i am using Beeline.                                                                      sql_v= select 'create table table_name from user_tab_columns where ...;'

Comment: I think I understand that part... So you have some file with just lines of queries? Is there a single column Hive table over that file that you can `INSERT INTO`? https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+DML#LanguageManualDML-InsertingvaluesintotablesfromSQL

Comment: yes a create table statement with many columns

Comment: You didn't answer my question. You can run insert into query using the value of the "dynamic query" assuming you've built a Hive table over the list of queries already stored in some existing hdfs location

Answer (score 0):

If the goal is to write the output of beeline to hdfs file then below options should work fine since both commands will pipe the standard output of beeline to hadoop commands as input which is recognized by (-).

```
beeline -u beeline_connection_string .... -e "$sql_v" | hadoop fs -put - /user/userid/file.hql

beeline -u beeline_connection_string .... -e "$sql_v" | hadoop fs -appendToFile - /user/userid/file.hql
```

Note:
1. It's a little unclear based on your question and comments on why can't you use the suggestion given by @cricket_007 and why to go for a beeline in particular.

```
echo "$sql_v" > file.hql
hadoop fs -put file.hql /user/userid/file.hql

beeline -u beeline_connection_string .... -e "$sql_v" > file.hql 
hadoop fs -appendToFile file.hql /user/userid/file.hql

beeline -u beeline_connection_string .... -e "$sql_v" > file.hql 
hadoop fs -put file.hql /user/userid/file.hql
```

2. If oozie shell action is used to run the bash script which containing the sql_v and beeline command, beeline needs to be present in the node where shell action will run if not you will face beeline not found an error.
   Refer: [beeline-command-not-found-error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58992680/beeline-command-not-found-error-while-executing-beeline-command-from-python-sc/59303787#59303787)